# Need to get next value from the mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

---

```
_id  |   name    |
------------------
ew293  item_1
13fse  item_2
dsv82  item_3
----------------
```

Lets assume this is the part of the data base, and i want to fetch a limited data
Ex:

```
db.collection.find({}, {name:1,_id:0}).limit(40)
```

Everytime i access, i want next set of 40 entries.

Is there any such command -- like the below one

```
db.collection.find({}, {name:1,_id:0}).limit(40).next()
```

I want next set of data only if it exists

And i access this in Python, so need a python code on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the skip() method. This is supported in PyMongo (Python Mongo Driver) as well.

To get first 40 entries:

```
db.collection.find({}, {name:1,_id:0}).limit(40)
```

To get the next 40 entries:

```
db.collection.find({}, {name:1,_id:0}).skip(40).limit(40)
```

To get another 40 entries:

```
db.collection.find({}, {name:1,_id:0}).skip(80).limit(40)
```